# ASP.NET Custom Validator - all or no values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to require all or none of a set of fields to be filled in. In other words if one is filled in all must be filled in. Here is what I tried. What am I missing to make this work?

ASP.NET markup:

```
<asp:CustomValidator
    id="CustomValidator"
    ErrorMessage="All or none of the fields must be filled out"
    ForeColor="Red"
    OnServerValidate="CustomValidator_ServerValidate"
    runat="server" />
```

C#:

```
protected void CustomValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(field1.Text) && 
         String.IsNullOrEmpty(field2.Text) && 
         String.IsNullOrEmpty(field3.Text)) || 
        (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(field1.Text) && 
         !String.IsNullOrEmpty(field2.Text) && 
         !String.IsNullOrEmpty(field3.Text))) 
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is a question and answer site... I fail to see your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your button submit, are you checking for `Page.IsValid`

The custom validator will not fire without that check.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(args) {
  if (Page.IsValid) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: No I wasn't but I was using CustomValidator.IsValid. I will try the page.isvalid

Comment: Even inside of if (Page.IsValid) {} it allows me to submit the form.

Comment: CustomValidator isn't going to prevent the form from being submitted, but should raise form errors that you can display in a ValidationSummary or the CustomValidator should display. As long as you're not continuing to process the form after checking Page.IsValid. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok I got it now. I did not process anything after the is valid. It didn't work when I added the Page.IsValid because I forgot to stop and restart the debugging IIS stupid mistake. Thank you for your help.